# Problem with Debian Squeeze and Wheezy mixed

Tags: debian

```
nrc1:/var/cache/apt# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.11.3-3) but 2.13-35 is installed
 locales : Depends: glibc-2.13-1 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I had this original Lenny install in use for thin client facility to students 
I successfully upgraded it to Squeeze long back 
During my leave for five long months, the other guy tried to install some things from Testing and Sid
Now as I'm trying `apt-get upgrade`
the above is the result

my current `sources.list`

```
deb http:// ftp .us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http:// ftp .us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-proposed-updates contrib non-free main
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates contrib non-free main
```

I have no idea how to cope up
the machine is in use by nearly 900 students but has all old software

Comment: There is no answer to this *in this form*.  Try including more information, e.g. your `sources.list`; what you have done so far and what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: You shouldn't mix releases - that's why they are separate releases in the first place. And as @sr_ says: provide more information.

Comment: Try using `aptitude`, it's pretty clever with these issues.

Comment: Try `apt-get dist-upgrade`, that may resolve it. Make sure to actually read what it says its going to do before pressing Y, to make sure it isn't removing a bunch of stuff you want.

Answer (score 4):

The installed `libc-bin` and `locales` packages are from Wheeze and do not fit to the `libc6` package from squeeze, which makes problems as the dependencies are not consistent.

Try to downgrade `libc-bin` and `locales`:

```
aptitude install libc-bin=2.11.3-3 locales=2.11.3-3
```

or

```
apt-get install libc-bin=2.11.3-3 locales=2.11.3-3
```

Other possibilities for downgrading packages are listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get).

As the current libc6 version is `2.11.3-4`, you might need to switch to it:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6=2.11.3-4 libc-bin=2.11.3-4 locales=2.11.3-4
```

There are probably more packages that you need to uprade.

Comment: Thank you very much for prompt and accurate solution -- gertvdijk, sr_,derobert and  jofel. The downgrading solution did work well